# future going out of scope while promise still exists

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, synchronization, future

What happens if I use wait_for on a future, which goes out of scope due to a timeout and then set_value is called on a promise? It would make little sense if it was undefined, however, I want to be sure and did not find an answer of my own. Example code below

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


void task1() {
    std::promise<void> promise;
    auto futureOutOfScopeWork = [&promise]() {
        std::future<void> future = promise.get_future();
        auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        if (status == std::future_status::ready) {
            std::cout << "in time" << std::endl;
        } else if (status == std::future_status::timeout) {
            std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "invalid state" << std::endl;
        }
    };  

    std::thread futureThread(futureOutOfScopeWork);
    futureThread.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(750));
    promise.set_value();
}



int main() {

    std::thread startEverything(task1);
    startEverything.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

the startEverythring thread initiates a promise. startEverything then
starts another thread which invokes get_future on the promise. The future then goes out of scope because of a timeout. Am I running into undefined behaviour here? get_future was called, the future was destroyed and set_value invoked in a promise whose linked future hast gone out of scope.

Comment: Capturing a reference to a local variable in a lambda (which is supposed to survive the scope it's created in) looks critical to me in any case - beyond threads and futures. FYI: [Dangling references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Dangling_references)

Comment: Sleeps are chosen such that promise should be in scope while required by the lambda. For a minimum example, this should be sufficient. True, for real a real application, lifetime has to be managed.

Comment: Sleep is a very insufficient tool for thread synchronization. It might work in 99.9 % in practice but I still wouldn't write code to rely on this.

Comment: I admit that I probably didn't get the actual intention of your question. So, it's said (for the records)... ;-)

Comment: You could have just joined normally instead of detatching and then sleeping. `detatch()` is an error or leads to an error almost every time.